# How to execute ChangeLog Class when user presses commit and push in Visual Studio Git Changes

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I created a class that will grab the latest commit changes with messages using Azure DevOps API. The only part that I am stuck at is that if there is a way that when a user presses Commit and Push or maybe Commit then Push in Git Changes in Visual Studio to trigger the custom class that I created to update the ChangeLog Txt file with the new entry?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipeline with [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) to run your ChangeLog Class.

When the repo has a new Commit (Commit and Push or maybe Commit then Push in Git Changes in Visual Studio ), it will trigger the Pipeline to run. You can store the CHANGELOG TXT FILE to other place with the Copy file task or publish the file as artifact in the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will have a look at the link that you shared and will look into the CI triggers.